# Tablet - Get Drawable Screen Resolution, Not Total Screen Resolution

Tags: java, android, android-canvas, tablet, screen-resolution

With tablets and some phones running 4.0 there are on screen controls.  I am developing a full screen canvas-based game.  I adjust my canvas to fit the screen size with a matrix.

On any device that has on screen buttons my app currently draws part of the games' controls under those buttons.

Is there a way to determine the drawable screen resolution, IE the resolution minus any onscreen buttons?

EDIT:

This is the way I'm testing for resolution

```
Display display = ((Activity) gameContext).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 

Log.d("Display.getWidth(): ", Integer.toString(display.getWidth()));
Log.d("Display.getHeight(): ", Integer.toString(display.getHeight()));

DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
((Activity) gameContext).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

Log.d("Metrics.getWidth(): ", Integer.toString(metrics.widthPixels));
Log.d("Metrics.getHeight(): ", Integer.toString(metrics.heightPixels));
```

Comment: https://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/msg/4e87f16dd02f3209

Answer (score 0):

Use the Android [`DisplayMetrics`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html) class.  The data it returns is the area available for the app to use, not including the on-screen controls and so forth.

Comment: Right now I'm using: `Display display = ((Activity) context).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();` and then `display.getWidth()` and `display.getHeight()`  The documentation for the stuff you provided looks like it returns the same info.  It makes no mention of working around the ActionBar.

Comment: Those are the right values.  Indeed, you'll find that contrary to one's intuition, getting the full screen size (such that the number of hardware pixels matches the number of pixels in your query result) is kind of difficult.  The thing you want is very easy.

Comment: Testing with 3.2 on an emulator display.XXX worked perfectly.  On 3.0 however the metrics and display objects both returned the same information.  I've put the actual logic I'm using above.

Comment: Yes.  That is the expected behavior.  On a 1280x800 tablet in landscape orientation, both of those should spit out values like 1280x720 or so, which accounts for the on-screen controls. That's the area available for your app to occupy, which is what you asked for.

Comment: That doesn't seem to solve the problem though.  On 3.2 the resolution I got allowed me to adjust my game to fit the usable area.  On 3.0 the resolution was the entire screen, so my game sat under the bottom bar.

Comment: Evidently the API changed, then.  If necessary, you can create subclasses that are created based on the device's OS version.